# From where comes the parent argument (PySide)?

Tags: python, pyside, init, super

In this example, from where comes the `parent` argument, who provides it?

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.do_something() #sanity check
        self.cw = ChildWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.show()

    def do_something(self):
        print 'doing something!'


class ChildWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.do_something_else)

        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.parent().do_something)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def do_something_else(self):
        print 'doing something else!'
```

Comment: What you've shown us is the *definition* of the classes, now show us where you're using the `ChildWidget` class? That's where you pass in the `parent` too.

Comment: Is it `self` in parenthesis from `self.cw = ChildWidget(self)` in `class MainWindow`?

Comment: Yes, there's your answer. In this particular case, `self` in `MainWindow` is the parent, so the `MainWindow` instance is the parent. In general, whenever you have `__init__(self, anything)`, the parameter `anything` is defined whenever you create a new object of that type.

Comment: So, `parent` in `super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)` method is just a parameter sent to `__init__` method of `MainWindow` togheter with implicit `self`. What bothers me is that `__init__(self)`takes only one parameter, not two

Comment: And from where comes parent()  method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent and children are specific to Qt (C++). From the [doc of QObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#details):

> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a
>   QObject with another object as parent, the object will automatically
>   add itself to the parent's children() list. The parent takes ownership
>   of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its
>   destructor.

`QWidget` and a lot of other class inherits from`QObject`, so it apply to them too. For every children, the `parent()` method returns a pointer to the parent object.

Basically, your creates widget with parents so they can be deleted properly.
Common case, your main window is the parent - or grandparent - of all your widgets: when you close the window, everything is deleted in the right order.

---

From your comment, I think your also confused with the use of`super()`. It does **not** call the parent of the widget.

Another way to write this:

```
class ChildWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)
```

is to call the init method of `QWidget` directly:

```
class ChildWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(parent)
```

`ChildWidget` inherits from `QWidget` (that's how we defined the class). In the init method, you need to call the default constructor of `QWidget`. Otherwise you won't be able to use the default methods and attributes of `QWidget` (try and see...).
If given a parent, it will also organize itself accordingly. It will add itself to the parent `children` method, and keep a reference to its parent.

Comment: Now I undestand, I think :) Parameter `parent` could be any word and it goes to ChildWidget's `__init__` just to be passed to `QtGui.QWidget.__init__(parent)` , so that QWidget knows who its parent is.